# If $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f^2(x)) = L > 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists and equals $\sqrt{L}$

Tags: calculus

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f^2(x)) = L > 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists and equals $\sqrt{L}$

Why is this false? I don't understand how to even know if such claims are false or true... If it's false - what would be a counter example?

Comment: What if $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=-\sqrt{L}$?

Comment: What if $f(x) = \sqrt{L}\cdot (-1)^{\mathbb{1}_A(x)}$ where $A$ is a dense subset of the real line?

Comment: What if $f(x) = -1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$f(x) = (-1)^n \text{ whenever }x\in[n,n+1)$$
Then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ doesn't even exist in the first place, even though $\lim_{x \to \infty} f^2(x)$ exists.